# How can I group an array with nested array?

Tags: javascript

Does anyone know a simple way to group an array with nested array?
For example, i have an array of animals:

```
[
  ['Cat', 'Dog', 'Monkey'],
  ['my pet', 'it is animals', 'terrestrial animals']
]
```

I want to make new array with format that's grouped by `['Cat', 'Dog', 'Monkey']`:

```
[
  {
    groupTitle: 'Cat',
    relations: ['my pet', 'it is animals', 'terrestrial animals']
  },
  {
    groupTitle: 'Dog',
    relations: ['my pet', 'it is animals', 'terrestrial animals']
  },
  {
    groupTitle: 'Monkey',
    relations: ['my pet', 'it is animals', 'terrestrial animals']
  }
]
```

How can i do it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Using [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
const arr = [
  ['Cat', 'Dog', 'Monkey'],
  ['my pet', 'it is animals', 'terrestrial animals']
]; // original data
const [groupTitles, relations] = arr; // array destructuring to get individual sub-arrays

const result = groupTitles.map(groupTitle => ({
  groupTitle,
  relations
}));

console.log(result); // print result
```

---

I used the following approach to achieve your desired outcome.

1. Use Array [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to get the individual arrays from the original array.
2. [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) through the animals array to get the desired array of objects and store it in a result variable.

---

## Using [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
const arr = [
  ['Cat', 'Dog', 'Monkey'],
  ['my pet', 'it is animals', 'terrestrial animals'],
]; // original array

const result = arr[0].reduce((a, b) => {
  return [
    ...a, // previously calculated values
    { // new value
      groupTitle: b,
      relations: arr[1],
    },
  ];
}, []);

console.log(result); // print result
```

The same result can also be achieved using `reduce()` method as required.

Comment: Great answer, but can i replace it with `reduce()` method?

Comment: I can't think of a way to do it with a `reduce()` at this moment. It seems you are actually "expanding" the array to achieve the result. Feel free to add to the answer if you get a way to it though.

Comment: Not a problem! On a lighter note, I guess the down-votes for this post might be because you did not mention any work you tried yourself and got stuck. The SO community is kind of strict when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I will take note of this!

Comment: @ALittleGirl why the interest of doing it with `reduce()` ?

Comment: @ALittleGirl, updated the answer by adding a `reduce()`. I am not sure if this is the best possible solution, though. hth

Comment: @Gass yes. Even though using `reduce()` is possible, I don't think `reduce()` fits in this use-case since we are not reducing it to a smaller product of the original array.

Comment: @deekeh well done, it was not an easy thing to do with reduce(). I was interested to know why the interest to do it with reduce since I think is one of worst ways to approach it, since is just overcomplicating things..

Comment: @Gass i was thinking the same. using `reduce()` here looks like we are reducing the array to a larger array, which seems like increasing the complexity of the snippet by A LOT.

Answer (score 2):

You can make a nested iteration using for loop for example:

```
const arr = [
  ["Cat", "Dog", "Monkey"],
  ["my pet", "it is animals", "terrestrial animals"],
];

let newArr = [];

for (let i = 0; i <= arr.length; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < arr[0].length; j++) {}
  newArr.push({ groupTitle: arr[0][i], relations: arr[1] });
}

console.log(newArr);
```

Answer (score 2):

Using destructuring assignments

```js
const arr = [
  ['Cat', 'Dog', 'Monkey'],
  ['my pet', 'it is animals', 'terrestrial animals']
]

let a,b,c, obj, newArr = [];

[a,b,c] =  arr[1]

arr[0].forEach(el => {

  obj = {
    groupTitle: el,
    relations: [a,b,c]
  }
  newArr.push(obj)
})

console.log(newArr)
```